# Is it possible to pattern match by function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

For example I have a function in haskell:

`foo :: Int a => (a -> a -> b) -> a -> b`

I want to pattern match by the first argument:

`foo (+) a = a + a`

`foo (-) a = a - a`

However, this code causes a compiler error.
I tried to use guards, but it didn't help too.
Is it possible to implement such pattern matching?

Comment: the short answer is "no". But if you only ever want to run `foo` with `(+)` or `(-)`, or any shortish list of specific functions, you can make an enumeration type that corresponds to it, and then pattern match on that: eg `foo Plus a = a + a` where you have `data Operation = Plus | Minus` or similar.

Comment: That code doesn't cause a compiler error here -- at least, not in the pattern matching. If you fix the type (by deleting `Int a =>`), the code compiles fine... though it may not mean what you want it to mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to pattern match by function in Haskell?

**No**. It is one of the consequences of [*Rice's theorem* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) that it is impossible to determine in general if two functions are equivalent. This thus means that it is possible to construct a function that can add two numbers together, but it is impossible for the compiler to proof that that function is equivalent to `(+)`.

If we would use reference equality, then `\x y -> x + y` should not match with the pattern whereas passing `(+)` directly would match. This would be rather bizar. Imagine that you have a function `f 0 = abs`, or `f 0 x = abs x`. It would be quite strange that a (small) implementation detail of a function could determine the behavior of another function.

The function definition is hower correct (tested this on a GHC 9.0.1 and 8.6.5). It however will not check if the function is `(+)`: you define a variable named `(+)` that you can use in the body of the function. You can use it as an infix operator, like `x + y`, or as `(+) x y`. But the function definition is identical to:

```
foo :: (a -> a -> b) -> a -> a -> b
foo g x y = g x y
```

or

```
foo :: (a -> a -> b) -> a -> a -> b
foo g x y = x `g` y
```

If you turn the `-Wname-shadowing` warning on, it will throw a warning that you have a temporary variable that clashes with a variable from a context above:

```
ghci> f (+) x y = x + y

<interactive>:1:3: warning: [-Wname-shadowing]
    This binding for ‘+’ shadows the existing binding
      imported from ‘Prelude’ (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Num’)
```

The signature of your function probably causes that much errors, the signature here should be:

```
f :: (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> c
f (+) x y = x + y
```

but again, this will *not* match with the `(+)` function defined in the Prelude.

If you need some parameter to determine a function, you can - as [@RobinZigmond says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70102933/is-it-possible-to-pattern-match-by-function-in-haskell#comment123922702_70102933) - make a type that represents certain functions, for example:

```
data FunctionSelector = Add | Sub

foo :: Num a => FunctionSelector -> a -> a -> a
foo Add = (+)
foo Sub = (-)
```